# AEM RTE thresholds plugin

Tags: plugins, aem, rte

I want to limit the number of characters that can be added into a richtext field. Somebody knows how the RTE thresholds plugin works? It doesn't seem to work just like that.

This is my dialog:

```
<headline
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Headline"
    name="./headline"
    xtype="richtext">
    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <thresholds
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            thresholds="[20;yellow,25;red]"/>
        <misctools
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="[specialchars]">
         </misctools>
        <spellcheck
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="[checktext]"/>
        <justify
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="[]"/>
        <lists
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="[]"/>
        <links
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            features="[modifylink,unlink]"
            name="./links1"/>
    </rtePlugins>
</headline>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AEM RTE does not support Thresholds Plugin Out of the Box. Your implementation seems to have implemented such a custom plugin. So, you will need to have a look at that implementation to know how to configure character limit.